# Crosswalks on ios - how to import 'XWalkView.h' When use it in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crosswalk-runtime

I try to import 'XWalkView.h' all the day,but I can't,It always appears 'not found',I know little about Swift...

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that "XWalkView.h" is added in your project by "Show in Finder". If that file is not there inside your project folder then try to add "XWalkView.h" after removing old copy.

Comment: When i  use file of swift,it could work,But objective-C could't.Your method that i had try.